# transform a matrix to the reduced row echelon form in Ruby

Tags: ruby, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm working on an [open source project](https://github.com/fogonthedowns/Rubychem) written in ruby, and I have hit an area where an algorithm requires the use of [Linear Algebra](http://www.saintjoe.edu/~karend/m244/ChemicalEquations.pdf). I'm looking for a gem to transform a matrix to the reduced row echelon form.

Basically following this (very detailed) series of steps:

http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi?c=rref

to convert

```
require 'matrix'
Matrix[[12, 0, -1, 0], [26, 0, 0, -2], [0, 2, -2, -1]]
```

to

```
Matrix[[1,0,0,-1/13],[0,1,0,-37/26],[0,0,1,-12/13]]
```

Can this be accomplished with standard ruby libraries in few steps? Or does a linear algebra gem exist?

Comment: Yes Seriously. I am looking for a gem that solves for reduced row echelon form. Do either of these do it? I can't find a method. Otherwise I will bog my code down with my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help - http://rubyforge.org/projects/linalg/ ?

Basic description reads - Linalg is a fast, LAPACK-based library for real and complex matrices. Current functionality includes: singular value decomposition, eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a general matrix, least squares, LU, QR, Schur, Cholesky, stand-alone LAPACK bindings.

Comment: I am pretty sure this solves your problem -: http://linalg.rubyforge.org/ ...It has examples too.